# Extract particular column from CSV file in scala (Spark)

Tags: scala, csv

I have csv file like:

[image]

I want to extract only the column "Summary" out of the above file.

I wrote code:

```
val read_file2 = sc.textFile("/home/hari/sample_data_exp/extract_column_only.csv") 
read_file2.collect()

val tmp1 = read_file2.map { line => val parts = line.split(',')
parts.drop(3).take(1)
```

But this giving output as :

[image]

Many "Array()" is coming. I want only the values of that column "Summary", no blank arrays in between.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only the summary part without having intermediate arrays, but a single flat sequence, use `flatMap`:

```
val summaries = file.flatMap(_.split(',')(3))
```

But looking at the CSV, you'd probably want to retrieve some kind of identifier, so maybe a `Tuple2[String, String]` would be better:

```
val idToSummary = file.map(line => {
  val lines = line.split(',')
  (lines(2), lines(3))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a dedicated CSV library, since the CSV format has many surprising edge cases that a simple "read line by line, split by ," doesn't deal with.

There are various quality CSV libraries - scala-csv, purecsv, jackson-csv... I'm going to recommend [kantan.csv](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.csv) because I'm the author and feel it's a good choice, but I readily admit to being biased.

Anyway, assuming you have the kantan.csv library in your classpath, here's how to do it (assuming `content` is a `java.io.File`):

```
import kantan.csv.ops._

content.asUnsafeCsvReader[List[String]](',', true).collect {
  case _ :: _ :: s :: _ => s
}
```

This turns your file into an iterator on CSV rows, where each row is represented as a `List[String]`, and then maps each row into the value of its third column (rows that don't have three or more columns are ignored).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
val tmp1 = read_file2.map(_.split(",")).map( p=>p(3)).take(100).foreach(println)
```

use p(0) for the first field and p(3) for the fourth one etc.

Comment: Yes , i got what i wanted. Its array[String]. Could you tell me how to iterate through every element, or how to retrieve a specific location element?

Comment: What do you mean by specific location? Ordered by what?  Specific fields (columns) can be extracted by specifying the place using the method I showed or by a name using some CSV package...

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not huge, you could load it in memory:

```
val tmp1 = file.map { line => line.split(',')(3) }
```

Or a bit more concise:

```
val tmp1 = file.map(_.split(',')(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
val read_file2 = sc.textFile("path")

read_file2.map(_.split(",")(3)).collect
```

If you want to fetch column values based on column names you can use spark-csv databricks library

```
val df=sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("pathToCSv")
df.select("columnName").collect() // here Summary
```